# How to create windows service application which will be automatically added to Windows services?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-services

I created in VS windows service application (I used this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer) and I used developer command prompt and installutil to install this application to Windows Service. How to create windows service  application in VS which will be automatically added to Windows  services (without using developer command pormpt)? Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: It's kindof expected that services will be installed by an installer - e.g. something that'll use MSI in some form. There are various options, some built into VS, some available for free or for trials, for authoring installation packages.

Comment: can you tell me wich options are built in VS?

Comment: Depending on which version of VS you're using and what options you chose to install, there may be a Visual Studio Installer Project template and/or Installshield (something, stripped down) Edition. If neither is present, the Installer Project should be installable from the VS extension gallery, IIRC. Personally I go with WiX but some feel it has too steep a learning curve (it does, but it's more about forcing familiarity with MSI internals, which stand you in good stead no matter which technology you actually use)

Answer (score 0):

> How to create windows service application in VS which will be automatically added to Windows services (without using developer command pormpt)?

Short answer, **you can't.**

1. It requires admin rights, which by default VS is not running in
2. Automatically deploying services is a bit of a security risk
3. Deployment can sometimes fail if the service is already running